# Como faço para incluir o texto com o resultado no meu modal com innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, modal

Fiz uma função que calcula o valor recebido por um input e gera um resultado que deveria ser mostrado em um modal, o modal aparece com o título e o span bonitinho, mas o p com o resultado não aparece de forma alguma, atualmente o código está assim, mas já tentei pegando a classe da div "modal-content", a div anterior que é a "modal", tentei também com innerText e innerContent e aconteceu a mesma coisa. Fico agradecido se alguém puder ajudar, o código está logo abaixo.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Sua conversão</h2>
                <p class="modal-text"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="dolar-real">
                <div class="content-text">
                    <p>Dólar para real</p>
                    <img src="./assets/coin.png" alt="Dólar">
                </div>

                <div class="entrada">
                    <input type="text" id="dolarToReal">
                    <button id="btnDolarToReal" onclick="dolarParaReal()"><img src="./assets/Group.png" alt="Botão de conversao"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function dolarParaReal() { //Função para calcular e mostrar o resultado
    var valor = document.getElementById('dolarToReal').value;
    var valorNumero = parseFloat(valor);

    var resultado = valorNumero * 5.71;
    var mostrarValor = `O valor convertido é: ${resultado}`;
    document.getElementsByClassName('modal-text').innerHTML = mostrarValor;  
    
    abrirModal();
}

function abrirModal() { //função para abrir o modal
    myModal.style.visibility = "visible";
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]

span.onclick = function fecharModal() { //função para fechar o modal
    myModal.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A função **document.getElementsByClassName** retorna uma **Array**, pois múltiplos elementos podem ter a classe especificada.

Mudar de `document.getElementsByClassName('modal-text').innerHTML` para `document.getElementsByClassName('modal-text')[0].innerHTML` vai funcionar no seu caso.

Segue um exemplo funcionado: https://jsfiddle.net/1bcaxgre/3/

Porém, recomendo não utilizar classes para para fazer essa atribuição de texto. Se outro elemento possuir a mesma classe e estiver posicionado mais acima na estrutura html, o código vai alterar outro elemento que não o desejado.
Sugiro que altere o **getElementsByClassName** para **getElementById** como utilizou para obter o valor do elemento **input**.

Algumas referências interessantes:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score -2):

Já tentou retirar o MostraValor e colocar o resultado direto na tag p? ficaria assim:

```js
function dolarParaReal() { //Função para calcular e mostrar o resultado
    var valor = document.getElementById('dolarToReal').value;
    var valorNumero = parseFloat(valor);

    var resultado = valorNumero * 5.71;
    document.getElementsByClassName('modal-text').innerHTML = `O valor convertido é: ${resultado}`;

    abrirModal();
}

function abrirModal() { //função para abrir o modal
    myModal.style.visibility = "visible";
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]

span.onclick = function fecharModal() { //função para fechar o modal
    myModal.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Sua conversão</h2>
                <p class="modal-text"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="dolar-real">
                <div class="content-text">
                    <p>Dólar para real</p>
                    <img src="./assets/coin.png" alt="Dólar">
                </div>

                <div class="entrada">
                    <input type="text" id="dolarToReal">
                    <button id="btnDolarToReal" onclick="dolarParaReal()"><img src="./assets/Group.png" alt="Botão de conversao"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Eu tentei aqui e continuou na mesma, mas foi um bom jeito de resumir o código.